# Powerbi - DAX: COUNT & GROUP BY - Count all coversation id's per Queue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been struggling with the next one. I need to make the sum of every unqique conversation ID per Queue.

There are 2 Tables I would like to us: Query and Segment.
First attempt to use "Group By"

```
Total Answered Calls = 
GROUPBY(segment;queue[name];"Total Answered"; COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP();COUNT(segment[conversationid])
))
```

I keep on recieving the error "The expression refers to multiple Columns [...] cannot be converted to scalar value.

Dit I use "Group B"y wrong or do I need another approach?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well this did the trick.

```
Total Answered Calls = (SUMX(SUMMARIZE(segment; segment[queueid];"Total Answered"; [Calls Answered]);[Total Answered]))
```

Thanks anyway!